# how to download sourcecode from SudzC

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sudzc

i generated a source code from sudzC, but i did not find the download option , please let me know how to download it

Comment: Bingo... They are charging now.

Comment: any other website or ways to do it Jennis

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/). Here are instructions [how it works](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions).

Hope that helps.